# Is there a particular sequence in this row of numbers?

Tags: c, loops, sequence

I need to create a list with 14 elements, for each element the input integer must be 1,2,5,10,20,50,100 and then reversed. It would be silly to write int a = 1, b = 2, ....
So is there a way to loop this?
For instance, if I'd make a for loop, how could i make a connection between the required value and "i"?

Comment: With an array. `int array[14] = { 1,2,5,10,20,50,100,100,50,20,10,5,2,1 };` You can then access each element with a `for` loop.

Comment: To add to what @WeatherVane wrote, you can make the look-up array `static` and `const`. You could even make it an array of `char` if you are really stingy about space (although making it `char` _might_ increase the size of the code more than the savings achieved by using a narrower type).

Comment: Check [https://oeis.org/A051109](https://oeis.org/A051109) , if you can translate this python script to C you got it: `print( [ ((n % 3) ** 2 + 1) * 10**int(n/3) for n in range(7)] )` --> (where 7 is the number of elements of the sequence)

Answer (score 1):

```
    for (int x = 0; x < 14; x++) {
        int y = 1 *            (x-1)/-1 * (x-2)/-2 * (x-3)/-3 * (x-4)/-4 * (x-5)/-5 * (x-6)/-6 * (x-7)/-7 * (x-8)/-8 * (x-9)/-9 * (x-10)/-10* (x-11)/-11* (x-12)/-12* (x-13)/-13
            +   2 * (x-0)/ 1            * (x-2)/-1 * (x-3)/-2 * (x-4)/-3 * (x-5)/-4 * (x-6)/-5 * (x-7)/-6 * (x-8)/-7 * (x-9)/-8 * (x-10)/-9 * (x-11)/-10* (x-12)/-11* (x-13)/-12
            +   5 * (x-0)/ 2 * (x-1)/ 1            * (x-3)/-1 * (x-4)/-2 * (x-5)/-3 * (x-6)/-4 * (x-7)/-5 * (x-8)/-6 * (x-9)/-7 * (x-10)/-8 * (x-11)/-9 * (x-12)/-10* (x-13)/-11
            +  10 * (x-0)/ 3 * (x-1)/ 2 * (x-2)/ 1            * (x-4)/-1 * (x-5)/-2 * (x-6)/-3 * (x-7)/-4 * (x-8)/-5 * (x-9)/-6 * (x-10)/-7 * (x-11)/-8 * (x-12)/-9 * (x-13)/-10
            +  20 * (x-0)/ 4 * (x-1)/ 3 * (x-2)/ 2 * (x-3)/ 1            * (x-5)/-1 * (x-6)/-2 * (x-7)/-3 * (x-8)/-4 * (x-9)/-5 * (x-10)/-6 * (x-11)/-7 * (x-12)/-8 * (x-13)/-9
            +  50 * (x-0)/ 5 * (x-1)/ 4 * (x-2)/ 3 * (x-3)/ 2 * (x-4)/ 1            * (x-6)/-1 * (x-7)/-2 * (x-8)/-3 * (x-9)/-4 * (x-10)/-5 * (x-11)/-6 * (x-12)/-7 * (x-13)/-8
            + 100 * (x-0)/ 6 * (x-1)/ 5 * (x-2)/ 4 * (x-3)/ 3 * (x-4)/ 2 * (x-5)/ 1            * (x-7)/-1 * (x-8)/-2 * (x-9)/-3 * (x-10)/-4 * (x-11)/-5 * (x-12)/-6 * (x-13)/-7
            + 100 * (x-0)/ 7 * (x-1)/ 6 * (x-2)/ 5 * (x-3)/ 4 * (x-4)/ 3 * (x-5)/ 2 * (x-6)/ 1            * (x-8)/-1 * (x-9)/-2 * (x-10)/-3 * (x-11)/-4 * (x-12)/-5 * (x-13)/-6
            +  50 * (x-0)/ 8 * (x-1)/ 7 * (x-2)/ 6 * (x-3)/ 5 * (x-4)/ 4 * (x-5)/ 3 * (x-6)/ 2 * (x-7)/ 1            * (x-9)/-1 * (x-10)/-2 * (x-11)/-3 * (x-12)/-4 * (x-13)/-5
            +  20 * (x-0)/ 9 * (x-1)/ 8 * (x-2)/ 7 * (x-3)/ 6 * (x-4)/ 5 * (x-5)/ 4 * (x-6)/ 3 * (x-7)/ 2 * (x-8)/ 1            * (x-10)/-1 * (x-11)/-2 * (x-12)/-3 * (x-13)/-4
            +  10 * (x-0)/10 * (x-1)/ 9 * (x-2)/ 8 * (x-3)/ 7 * (x-4)/ 6 * (x-5)/ 5 * (x-6)/ 4 * (x-7)/ 3 * (x-8)/ 2 * (x-9)/ 1             * (x-11)/-1 * (x-12)/-2 * (x-13)/-3
            +   5 * (x-0)/11 * (x-1)/10 * (x-2)/ 9 * (x-3)/ 8 * (x-4)/ 7 * (x-5)/ 6 * (x-6)/ 5 * (x-7)/ 4 * (x-8)/ 3 * (x-9)/ 2 * (x-10)/ 1             * (x-12)/-1 * (x-13)/-2
            +   2 * (x-0)/12 * (x-1)/11 * (x-2)/10 * (x-3)/ 9 * (x-4)/ 8 * (x-5)/ 7 * (x-6)/ 6 * (x-7)/ 5 * (x-8)/ 4 * (x-9)/ 3 * (x-10)/ 2 * (x-11)/ 1             * (x-13)/-1
            +   1 * (x-0)/13 * (x-1)/12 * (x-2)/11 * (x-3)/10 * (x-4)/ 9 * (x-5)/ 8 * (x-6)/ 7 * (x-7)/ 6 * (x-8)/ 5 * (x-9)/ 4 * (x-10)/ 3 * (x-11)/ 2 * (x-12)/ 1;
    }
```

*short explanation: in every row, when x is one of 0 to 13, most multiplications will yield `0`, the one that does not needs to be divided to correct the value*

But the array lookup option is better in ... oh ... so many many ways :)

See [ideone](https://ideone.com/q9Oa7o)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: [very very very basic curve fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the following in a loop

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const int N = 10;

    int multiplier = 1;
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {

        int value;

        switch ( i % 3 )
        {
        case 0: 
            value = 1 * multiplier;
            break;

        case 1:
            value = 2 * multiplier;
            break;

        case 2:         
            value = 5 * multiplier;
            break;
        }

        printf ( "%d ", value );

        if ( ( i + 1 ) % 3 == 0 ) multiplier *= 10;
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 5 10 20 50 100 200 500 1000
```

Comment: Brilliant Vlad!